# Splash screen and icon is not coming in react native expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen

I have build react native expo app everthing is working fine but splash screen and app icon is not coming.

Here is my `app.json`:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "testing",
    "slug": "testing",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to clean cache and also tried to rebuild the project but still not getting the app icon and splash screen.

everything is up-to-date in my project.

Please help me with the solution. I would love to hear responses from your.

Comment: Can you share your `app.json`

Comment: {
  "expo": {
    "name": "testing",
    "slug": "testing",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
.......
}

Comment: please let me know what else I can provide you?

Comment: (1) is your icon in `./assets/icon.png`? (2) What's the dimension of your `icon.png`? (3) Is it not working on iOS and Android or one of them? (4) Are you on a managed expo project or ejected one?

Comment: 1- @devpolo yes this is my icon->./assets/icon.png
2- I have the same dimension as the default expo assets
3- I'm trying on Android
4- I didn't understand this point. Please elaborate on this point if possible.

Comment: (4) are you opening your app in expo go?

Comment: @devpolo yes Im opening it in expo go

Answer (score 4):

I have tried this and fortunately, it's working now:

```
npx expo prebuild --clean
```

then

```
npx expo prebuild
```